# Performance of a simple jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am learning jQuery and I have been trying to make a slider from scratch. Even though it works, the performance is not as smooth as I would like. I even tried toying with DOM caching, but performance still isn't perfect.

How can I improve it and, if possible, how can I shorten the code even more?

```js
'use strict';

var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slides = $('#slides');
var $slide = $('.slide');

var slideWidth = $(window).width();
$('#slider, #slider img').css({
    'width': slideWidth
});

var slidesWidth = slideWidth * ($('.slide').length + 1);
$slides.css({
    'width': slidesWidth
});

var currentSlide = 1;

$(function () {
    var animationSpeed = 1600; 
    var pause = 5000;

    setInterval(function () {
        $slides.animate({
            'margin-left': '-=' + (slideWidth + 5.5)
        }, animationSpeed, function () {
            currentSlide++;
            if (currentSlide === $slide.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slides.css({
                    'margin-left': '0'
                });
            }
        });
    }, pause);
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
  
body {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 320px;
}

#slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

#slides {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slide { 
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML relevant segment -->

<div id="slider">
    <ul id="slides">
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://bit.ly/1ez08le"/></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://bit.ly/1ez08le"/></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://bit.ly/1ez08le"/></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://bit.ly/1ez08le"/></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://bit.ly/1ez08le"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is there online version?

Comment: One problem is that you're moving all the elements when you only need to move two of them.

Comment: @metamorph_online (ja, I fixed it :D)

Comment: @Eth To be honest, the slider is pretty smooth for me - it could be the svgs you are using.

Comment: Ouch, sorry I am a new user and just realized that I should have commented here and not creating a NEW ANSWER - Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the prompt comments.

@metamorph_online:
There is an online version using all .jpg in:
www.crypto777.com

@jcuenod:
What I animate are the #slides container which needs to be set a width, calculated in this case via jQuery based on the viewport width (which the slides also follow). I couldn't find a way to make it more effective, but I would be glad to hear ideas on how to do so :)

Also, if someone could comment about how to improve the DOM cache also would be fantastic since I have hit a wall in what refers to improve it more.

Thank you guys.